# figure and figure* with inconsistent orders

Tags: floats, formatting, positioning

**How to have figures of both types `\figure{}` and `\figure*{}` ordered correctly among one another?**

I have elements of both types `\figure{}` and `\figure*{}` in a document (its class is `\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}`).

My problem is that, if I use only `\figure` (no star), all figures in the document appear in ascending order, i.e., Figure 1, Figure 2, Figure 3, etc. The same happens if all figures are `\figure*`. However, when using both types, Latex messes them up. So, now, I have Figure 3, Figure 1, Figure 2, Figure 5, Figure 4.

It may be interesting to point out that Figures 1, 2 and 5 are just `\figure`, while Figures 3 and 4 are both `\figure*`, that is, figures of the same type are ordered correctly among one another, but not with figures of other type. This even seems like a bug, because, if they were different float types completely, why do they use the same numbering?

Comment: this was a long standing bug if you add `\usepackage{fixltx2e}` it should be fixed. It is also fixed (by default)  in the upcoming 2015 LaTeX release

Comment: that worked! thanks a bunch! if you add your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was a long standing bug if you add

```
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
```

it should be fixed. It is also fixed (by default) in the upcoming 2015 LaTeX release.